# In MS Access, how do I update a table record to its current value plus the count of records in a different table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

```
**tblMonthlyData**
ReportMonth  |  TotalItems  |  TotalVariances
Jan          |  5           |  0
Feb          |  1           |  1
Mar          |  2           |  0
Apr          |  8           |  4
May          |  4           |  0
Jun          |  5           |  0
Jul          |  3           |  0
Aug          |  5           |  0
Sep          |  9           |  3
Oct          |  1           |  0
Nov          |  7           |  0
Dec          |  6           |  0
```

*and*

```
**tblDailyData**
ID  |  ItemNum  |  CountedQty  |  SystemQty  |  Variance
1   |  Item1    |  4           |  4          |  0
2   |  Item2    |  8           |  5          |  -3
3   |  Item3    |  1           |  2          |  1
4   |  Item4    |  6           |  4          |  -2
```

For the sake of clarity, we'll say the above `tblDailyData` is from a count done today, 01/27/2017. `Variance` is a calculated field based on the data in both quantity fields.

I'm trying to add the count of records in `tblDailyData` to `TotalItems` in `tblMonthlyData` based on the date of the count (i.e. counts are done daily and each counts data needs to be added to the appropriate month in `tblMonthlyData`). So for the above example I'd need to add 4 (number of records) to `TotalItems` in `tblMonthlyData` for the `Jan` record, resulting in the updated record being 9, and add 3 (number of variances) to `TotalVariances`, resulting in the updated record being 3.

So far, I've tried using a Make Table Query for both total items counted and total number of variances, then using an Update Query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE tblMonthlyData
SET TotalItems = TotalItems + tblTempTotalItems.CountOfItems,
TotalVariances = TotalVariances + tblTempTotalVariances.CountOfVariances
WHERE Format$([ReportMonth],"mmm")=Format$(Now(),"mmm");
```

I've also tried a similar method using select queries to count records and variances (without creating the temporary tables) and running the update query based on those. Both methods result in Access prompting for the `CountOfItems` and `CountOfVariances` parameters when the update query is ran instead of just taking the values from the specified temporary table or select query.

This seemed like it'd be such a simple operation (query the count of records and variances, add them to the appropriate monthly record in separate table), but it turns out I can't figure out how to make it work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Normalizing your database would improve many things, including the ease of counting items and variances.  If you don't understand the 1st 3 words of this comment, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I've read about database normalization and its forms. I definitely struggle to get things setup already normalized in my first pass when making my small projects.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a situation for a table, but rather for some views/queries, which will always be up to date.

Use a `GROUP BY FORMAT([date_field],"mm/dd/yyyy")` clause in your query for daily item count (if you want to add that to a montlhy count, we will do that in ANOTHER query.

```
SELECT FORMAT([date_field],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS TotalItems 
FROM tblDailyData
GROUP BY Date
```

Call this query dailyTotalItems.

```
SELECT FORMAT([date_field],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS TotalItemsWithVariance, SUM(
FROM tblDailyData
WHERE NOT (Variance = 0) 
GROUP BY Date
```

Call this query dailyTotalItemsWithVariance.

```
SELECT MONTH([date_field]) As MonthDate, SUM(TotalItems) As TotalMonthlyItems
FROM dailyTotalItems
GROUP BY MonthDate
```

Call this query monthlyTotalItems.

```
SELECT MONTH([date_field]) As MonthDate, SUM(TotalItemsWithVariance) As TotalMonthlyItemsWithVariance
FROM dailyTotalItemsWithVariance
GROUP BY MonthDate
```

Call this query  monthlyTotalItemsWithVariance.

Then `LEFT JOIN` both on MonthDate.

```
SELECT * FROM monthlyTotalItems 
LEFT JOIN monthlyTotalItemsWithVariance ON monthlyTotalItems.MonthDate =  monthlyTotalItemsWithVariance.MonthDate
```

NOTE: `TotalItems` will always be `>= TotalItemsWithVariance` AND every date with a variance must have had a count.  So get ALL dates in monthlyTotalItems and left join to match the `monthlyTotalItemsWithVariance` items (which must be included, as shown above)

Comment: Honestly, the make table step was a solution I found through research but it sounded like a whole lot of extra steps for no reason. Glad to know I assumed correctly. I'm not really sure what to do with your query. It looks like it would query records by date in `tblDailyData`. I do not currently have a date field in `tblDailyData`, as it is a table with only the item info that needs to be counted.

Comment: Just finished reading your added details. when you say "call this table..." did you mean query? So query daily item totals, daily item variances, monthly item totals, and monthly item variances?

Comment: include a date field in your table, by all means!  and then JOIN everything together.  faster, cleaner, more elegant AND generates reliable data, IMO.

Comment: i did this all on paper since i dont have a running instance of access on this machine (tested on mysql), test it and tell me if does the trick (should get an up to date count, without the hassle of updating a table (arghh!!!!!).

Comment: So honestly, I don't think I'm seeing what all of this accomplishes. I've created the select queries for `dailyTotalItems`, `dailyTotalItemsWithVariance`, `monthlyTotalItems`, `monthlyTotalItemsWithVariance`, and a select query (`countData`) for the left join. This leaves me where I was before with multiple select queries, and the update query (detailed in the original question) which prompts for the parameters instead of  automatically pulling them from the specified select queries (explained in detail at the end of the original question). I'm unsure as to what I'm missing...

Comment: Okay so I think have a better way to frame my question with the information we've already discussed. If I have a select query that summarizes some information (prime example being the left join query you mentioned to summarize the other four queries), how do I update the appropriate `TotalItems` and `TotalVariances` fields in `tblMonthlyData` (in this case the `Jan` record) with the sum of its current value plus the respective query values?

Comment: I refrained from adding variances because you have not determined how you treat them in your system: 1. if you "fix" variances daily, the sum is valid (for example variance=-1, sum = -1).  on the other hand, if you take a week to fix it in your system, you will have true variance of -1 but a sum of -7.   nevertheless, variance sum should be calculated on a per item basis (`GROUP BY Date, ID`).  now, have you consider upvoting my answer (even if you dont accept it as the correct one)?